# Include Search Parameters Custom Paging SQL Query

Tags: sql, parameters, objectdatasource

***answered***

Having some trouble modifying an SQL query that is commonly used for ObjectDataSource custom paging.

Below is a custom ObjectDataSource paging SQL call, that will return only the results for a single page of information on the website gridview. This is often used for faster loading times.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ApplicationDescription DESC) AS PriceRank
FROM InstallationCodes
) AS ProductsWithRowNumber
WHERE
PriceRank > 0 AND
PriceRank <= (12);
```

The goal is to add a search parameter to filter the call before the result ordered and filtered down to the page size.

Here is an example search parameter so that the query will only return results with gold or null in the column FeatureString:

```
WHERE (FeatureString LIKE 'gold' OR FeatureString IS NULL)
```

How do we filter by parameter before reducing to page size?

Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ApplicationDescription DESC) AS PriceRank
FROM InstallationCodes ***WHERE FeatureString LIKE 'gold' OR FeatureString IS NULL***) 
AS ProductsWithRowNumber
WHERE
PriceRank > 0 AND
PriceRank <= (12);
```

remove the multiplication stars (***)